# How to call Observable from suspend method and wait for result

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have following method defined in a service

```
fun uploadFile(
        fileName: String,
): Observable<Status> {
    return Observable.fromCallable {
        fileUploadService.uploadFile(
               fileName
        )
    }
    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.ioScheduler)
}
```

What I want to do is invoke this method from suspend method what is the best way to invoke a Observable from suspend method and wait for results from Observable.

```
vieweModelScope.launch {
   coroutineScope {
        val deferredResults = async { uploadFileHelper(fileName) }
        val status = deferredResults.await()
   }
}

fun uploadFileHelper (fileName: String): Message {
        return uploadService.uploadFile(
                request = request,
            ).toBlocking().first()
}
```

I know, I could refactor above service to take out "fileUploadService.uploadFile" to method and invoke that directly. But I am trying to prototype RxJava Observable+Coroutine coexistence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using extension `suspend fun <T> ObservableSource<T>.awaitFirst(): T` from [kotlinx.coroutines.rx3](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx3/kotlinx.coroutines.rx3/io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.-observable-source/await-first.html) (or `awaitFirstOrDefault`, `awaitFirstOrElse`, `awaitFirstOrNull`, `awaitSingle`)

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
  val status = uploadService.uploadFile(request).awaitFirst()
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up if someone faces the same issue as me: I was getting NetworkOnMainThreadException when trying this. The solution is that line in the question, that is essential: `.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.ioScheduler)`